# Filter function score with Nest

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to build the following query using using the DSL syntax:

```
    GET /_search
    {
      "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "filter": { 
            "term": { "city": "Barcelona" }
          },
          "functions": [ 
            {
              "filter": { "term": { "features": "wifi" }}, 
              "weight": 1
            },
            {
              "filter": { "term": { "features": "garden" }}, 
              "weight": 1
            },
            {
              "filter": { "term": { "features": "pool" }}, 
              "weight": 2 
            }
          ],
          "score_mode": "sum", 
        }
      }
    }
```

However it seems there's no `filter` option in the function_score when using the NEST client. I can confirm the query works in elastic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure which version of Elasticsearch you're targeting, but there hasn't been a `filter` property on a `function_score` query since Elasticsearch 2.0, [when queries and filters were merged](https://www.elastic.co/blog/better-query-execution-coming-elasticsearch-2-0). NEST exposes what is available within the Elasticsearch API, so the property is available in NEST 1.x but not in any later versions.

[Filters on individual functions exist](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)

```
var response = client.Search<object>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .FunctionScore(fs => fs
            .Functions(fu => fu
                .Weight(w => w
                    .Weight(1)
                    .Filter(wf => wf
                        .Term("features", "pool")
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```